# what does this regex mean [^}]*

Tags: java, regex

This is a code I read on a forum.

```
public String replaceVariables(String input, Map<String, String> context) {
    if(context == null || input == null)
        return input;

    Matcher m = Pattern.compile( "\\$\\{([^}]*)\\}" ).matcher( input );
    // Have to use a StringBuffer here because the matcher API doesn't accept a StringBuilder -kg
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while(m.find()) {
        String value = context.get(m.group(1));
        if(value != null)
            m.appendReplacement(sb, value);
    }
    m.appendTail(sb);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

I am confuse about `[^}]*`. Can I use another character instead of `}`?

Comment: Did you read e.g. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean/22944075#22944075

Comment: Literally: "any character which is _not_ a closing bracket (`[^}]`), zero or more times (`*`)".

Comment: (sorry, I meant "brace", not "bracket")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `[]` is used in regular expression to denote a set of characters.

The `^` denotes the **not** operator. However, note that if the `^` is not the first character in the set, it won't be treated as an operation, but rather as a character. For example, `[1^2]` matches `1`, `^` and `2` (not `1` and anything that's not `2`) (thanks to [@Maroun Maroun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1735406/maroun-maroun))

Therefore, `[^}]` denotes a set of characters that's comprised of characters which **are not** `}`.

The `*` means that there can be infinite (including zero) repetitions of the set.

Comment: Good answer, but you might add that the `*` allows for zero repetitions. I.e., there don't have to be any non-`}` characters at all for the regex to match the string.

Comment: Also note that if `^` is not the first character, it'll loose its meaning. For example, `[1^2]` matches 1, ^ and 2 (not 1 and anything that's not 2).

Comment: Thanks, Maroun. Added that too. :)